# How to manage config files?

Tags: python, configuration, user-input

I have a python project with some packages and classes. Some of those classes read some values from standard input in their constructor (all of them call a specific `read_input` function).

I want to write a program to set different values for those inputs, then get the output, and set new inputs and so on. It's hard to pass the values to constructors because they call each other. I think it's better to change the `read_input` function so that it reads the inputs from a config file. Then I can change the config file from my program each time.

My questions are:

1. Is there any better way to do such a thing?
2. Is there any convention for managing this config file? should it be in any specific format? (I saw [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module which uses a specific file stucture.)
3. Where should I put the config file in the project? (Should I create a config package?)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your input data in a file, in the same sequence as you want to input it and then feed it into the program with redirection (this has nothing to do specifically with python) like:

file `data`:

```
your data
...
```

and you call it with
`python your_program.py < data`

Using `configparser` is ok to read `.ini` files but those are more common
to define program settings for runtime.